# Create big numbers by BCD - C++

Tags: c++, numbers, bcd

I want to create code that will help me get numbers bigger than MAXINT. I heard about that I can use Binary Code Decimal to do this, and then every two of decimal numbers(converted to BCD) of the bigger number keep in char. But how to do this? I should give string as input, then convert somehow to BCD every single decimal number? And how can I put two converted decimal numbers to one char? I'm new in C++ and don't know how can i do it.

P.S. I don't want to use libraries which are "special" for that kind of problems.

Comment: `I don't want to use libraries which are "special" for that kind of problems.` -> why not? when -> `I'm new in C++ and don't know how can i do it.`
also, what have you tried?

Comment: If you don't need efficiency, it will be much simpler to keep one digit per byte. If you do need efficiency, it would probably be better to use a binary rather than decimal representation. But if you really want BCD, learn about bitwise operations such as `digits = ((d1-'0') << 4) | (d2-'0')` or `digit = (digits>>4) & 0xf`

Comment: @MikeSeymour by binary representation you mean every single digit to binary?

Comment: @bingo157: I mean use each byte to represent 8 binary digits, not 2 decimal digits, making it more efficient for storage and arithmetic than BCD. Although that would make conversion to and from decimal less easy.

Comment: @MikeSeymour can you give me an example? Because I don't really know what you have on mind

Comment: @bingo157: Sorry, this isn't the place for an extended discussion. I simply mean that, if you want to store the number efficiently, you'd represent a large number with a string of bytes, each containing 8 bits of the number's binary representation (rather than 2 decimal digits as you're asking about). If you don't need efficiency, you could simply store one decimal digit in each byte, so that it's very easy to work with.

Comment: @MikeSeymour ok, nevermind, i've got this. You told me about that bitwise operations and that is what i was looking for. From the begininng my problem was to take big number, take every digit of it(for 123, we take 1, then 2, then 3), and for this digit we take his binary representation (for 1 is 0001 etc), put it in tmp uint8_t(or char), take second digit, and do this bitwise operation with or on tmp and second digit. That will solve the problem? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @bingo157: That sounds about right. If you have any specific questions, feel free to ask them, but asking for vague advice like this is off-topic I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm confused.  In 8 bits, you can store 256 values.  With BCD you can only store 99 values.  So how will you store more values than MAXINT?  You may want to use a *Big Number* library, or if you have sufficient ego and time, write your own.

Comment: I thnik it's about creating uint8_t array, where in every element you store 2 of digits in binary representation. Am I right @MikeSeymour?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this is actually quite simple. How about we try to take it to the next level?

Below is an implementation of a BCD number with infinite(or as much as memory can hold) size. It only supports positive integer numbers. I'll leave extending this to support negative numbers(or real numbers) as an exercise.

First things first: Yes, we want to get our number as a string and then build it up from that. Since it's only an integer, this is actually quite easy to do. We primarily create a helper function to aid us in identifying all the digits.

```
int char_to_int(const char c) {
  int ret = c - '0';
  if(ret > 9 || ret < 0) throw 1; // for simplicity. Use a class derived from std::exception instead.
  return ret;
}
```

We can now try to implement input and output for our big number.

### First Try

Having that helper guy, turning a string to a BCD-encoded buffer is easy. A common implementation may look like this:

```
int main() {
  unsigned char bignum[10]; // stores at most 20 BCD digits.
  std::memset(bignum, 0, sizeof(bignum));
  std::string input;
  std::cin >> input;
  try {
    if (input.size() > 20) throw 1; // Avoid problems with buffer overflow.
    for (int i=1;i<=input.size();i++) {
      int n = char_to_int(input[input.size()-i]);
      bignum[sizeof(bignum) - (i+1)/2] |= n << (i%2)*4; // These are bitwise operations. Google them!
    }
  }
  catch(int) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: Invalid input.\n";
    return 0; // Exit cleanly.
  }
  // bignum is now filled. Let's print it to prove.
  for (int i=0;i<sizeof(bignum);i++) {
    int first_digit = bignum[i] & '\x0F';     // Right side, doesn't need to shift.
    int second_digit = (bignum[i] & '\xF0')>>4; // Left side, shifted.
    std::cout << first_digit << second_digit;
  }
}
```

This is not very space-efficient, however. Note that we have to store all the 20 digits, even if our number is small! What if we needed 1000 digits? What if we need 1000 numbers that may or may not have these 1000 digits? It is also error-prone: Look that we had to remmember to initialize the array, and do a bounds check before conversion to avoid a buffer overflow.

### Second Try

We can improve our implementation using a std::vector:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<unsigned char> bignum; // stores any quantity of digits.
  std::string input;
  std::cin >> input;
  try {
    // For an odd number of digits we want a trailling zero at the end.
    if(input.size()%2) n.num_vec.push_back(char_to_int(input[0]));
    for (unsigned i=input.size()%2;i<input.size();i+=2) {
      int left  = char_to_int(input[i]);
      int right = char_to_int(input[i+1]);
      n.num_vec.push_back(0);
      n.num_vec.back() = left << 4;
      n.num_vec.back() |= right;
    }

  }
  catch(int) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: Invalid input.\n";
    exit(0); // Exit cleanly.
  }
  // bignum is now filled. Let's print it to prove.
  for (unsigned i=0;i<bignum.size();++i) {
    // Notice that we inverted this from the previous one! Try to think why.
    int first_digit = (bignum[i] & '\xF0')>>4; // Left side, shifted.
    int second_digit = bignum[i] & '\x0F';     // Right side, doesn't need to shift.
    if(i || first_digit) std::cout << first_digit; // avoid printing trailling 0.
    std::cout << second_digit;
  }
}
```

Lookin' good, but that is too cumbersome. Ideally, the bignumber user shouldn't have to deal with the vector positions and all that mumbo-jumbo. We want to write code that behaves like:

```
int main() {
  int a;
  cin >> a;
  cout << a;
}
```

And it should just work.

### Third Try

Turns out this is possible! Just wrap bignum into a class, with some helpful operators:

```
class bignum {
  std::vector<unsigned char> num_vec;
  template<typename T>
  friend T& operator<<(T& is, bignum& n);
  template<typename T>
  friend T& operator>>(T& os, bignum& n);
};

// Get input from any object that behaves like an std::istream (i.e.: std::cin)
template<typename T>
T& operator>>(T& is, bignum& n) {
  std::string input;
  is >> input;
  n.num_vec.reserve(input.size());
  if(input.size()%2) n.num_vec.push_back(char_to_int(input[0]));
  for (unsigned i=input.size()%2;i<input.size();i+=2) {
    int left  = char_to_int(input[i]);
    int right = (i+1) != input.size()?char_to_int(input[i+1]):0; // If odd number of digits, avoid getting garbage.
    n.num_vec.push_back(0);
    n.num_vec.back() = left << 4;
    n.num_vec.back() |= right;
  }
  return is;
}

// Output to any object that behaves like an std::ostream (i.e.: std::cout)
template<typename T>
T& operator<<(T& os, bignum& n) {
  for (unsigned i=0;i<n.num_vec.size();++i) {
    int first_digit = (n.num_vec[i] & '\xF0')>>4; // Left side, shifted.
    int second_digit = n.num_vec[i] & '\x0F';     // Right side, doesn't need to shift.
    if(i || first_digit) os << first_digit; // avoid printing trailling 0.
    os << second_digit;
  }
  return os;
}
```

Then our main function looks much more readable:

```
int main() {
  bignum a;
  try {
    std::cin >> a;
  }
  catch(int) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: Invalid input.\n";
    return 0; // Exit cleanly.
  }
  std::cout << a;
}
```

### Epilogue

And here we have it. Of course with no addition, multiplication, etc. operators, it isn't very useful. I'll leave them as an exercise. Code, code and code some more, and soon this will look like a piece of cake to you.

Please feel free to ask any questions. Good coding!

Comment: `(c - '0')` is perfectly correct and portable, because the C++ Standard itself requires that "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after `0` in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.", a guarantee you just claimed doesn't exist.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's nice to know. Edited to match.

Comment: @CássioRenan one question. If i use dynamic array(because i don't now what the size of number will be), how to get size of this aray(I need it for addition and substraction) but I don't want to do it with additional variable, because conclusion of a task is to do this with maximum memory saving.

Comment: @bingo157, there's two ways of getting the size of a sequence: **a)** Traversing it entirely, counting the elements(For that you need a "placeholder" element to indicate the end, using more memory anyway), or **b)** Knowing it beforehand(i.e.: keeping it in a variable). The benefits of **b** far exceed the keeping of a single variable in memory, **especially** for large sequences. `std::vector` does just that. Use member function `vec.size()` to get it.